# How to preview jsdoc comments in google doc scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, preview, jsdoc

I know that Issue 1731 has been raised requesting preview of jsdoc within the Google script editor. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1731

While we wait for that to be implemented, what's the best way to preview jsdoc comments that I'm adding to my published library, without requiring me to create a new version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update 2014: With libraries now supported by the Google Apps Script editor's autocompletion, it's possible to get immediate feedback about SOME of your library's jsdoc comments.

---

This solution isn't ideal - it doesn't provide the same look as published google script libraries - but at least I can work through my jsdoc comments to get a good idea of what they will look like, without constantly creating new versions of my library with no functional enhancements. *If someone can detail the additional steps to get the exact output we'd see from publishing, please share!*

This is what I've done on a Windows 7 PC. Similar steps may work on other platforms, ymmv.

- Get jsdoc3 by downloading the repository as a [zipfile](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/zipball/master).
- Uncompress into a convenient location. I used `C:\jsdoc`. This also installs the Rhino jvm that is needed by jsdoc3.

Next, you need to get your google script into a local file that can be parsed by jsdoc3. *Again, if anyone knows a better way, I'm all ears!*

- Set up a local directory for your google script project. `C:\myscript`, say.
- Go to your script in google docs / drive / whatever, and copy the whole thing to the system clipboard.

  ```
  <ctrl-A> <ctrl-C>
  ```
- Using your favorite text editor, paste the clipboard contents

  ```
  <ctrl-V>
  ```
- Save the results in a javascript file. `C:\myscript\testing.js`, say.

Alright, from here it's a matter of parsing the file, auditing the output, and editing your jsdoc comments until you're happy with them.

Output of jsdoc3 will go into an "out" directory.

- Open a command window in `C:\myscript`.
- Parse your javascript file.

  ```
  \jsdoc\jsdoc testing.js
  ```
- Open the output in your default browser.

  ```
  out\index.html
  ```
- Rinse and repeat, until you have your desired results.
- Copy & paste your edited script back into Google space, validate that your code hasn't broken, and make a new version to generate the documentation for your published library.

### Caveats:

- The format of the output is different than you'll see in a published Google Script Libary, but the content is largely the same. Remember that only a subset of jsdoc tags are supported by Google (@param and @returns only) - you can put others in your code, but they will be ignored.
- HTML tables can be included in your jsdoc comments, with limited customization options.

  - You must enclose ALL rows in `<tbody></tbody>` tags; rows within `<thead>` get ignored.
  - Further - all `<th>` get ignored. To make the first row stand out, use `<b></b>` tags.
  - Don't bother with any cell formatting, `align` etc. will be ignored.
  - You can specify width within a style attribute, and it survives.

### Example:

Here's an example of some elements that render in both jsdoc and googlescript doc:

```
/**
 * Demonstrate jsdoc with a table. Otherwise, meaningless gibberish.
 *
 * <table> 
 * <tbody>
 * <tr><td style="width: 75%"><b>Student Name</b></td><td style="width: 25%"><b>Idiocy Factor</b></td></tr>
 * <tr><td> John Smith      </td><td align=right>  18 </td></tr>
 * <tr><td> Sally Doe       </td><td align=right>  53 </td></tr>
 * <tr><td> Carmen Sandiego </td><td align=right>  90 </td></tr>
 * <tr><td> Tam O'Shanter   </td><td align=right> 180 </td></tr>
 * </tbody>
 * </table>
 *
 * Continuation of function description down here. Why not have an example?
 * <pre>
 * =myFunc($A8, $DV8 )
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param {String} your mother's name, e.g. <code>"Anne Murray"</code>
 * @param {String} date of birth, <code>DD/MM/YYYY</code>
 * @returns {Date} estimated date of demise
 * @returns {String} "Please try again." if error in input
 */
```

Not perfect, and with a fairly high PITA value. Still, jsdoc will make sure you get the syntax of any unsupported tags right, great for portability.

Comment: The Google Drive SDK now provides a way of [Importing and Exporting GAS Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export) so long as the project is not container-bound. That should allow you a better way of getting the project code down to the local machine.