# Google Apps Script auto-generated documentation see and prettyprint

Tags: google-apps-script, documentation, jsdoc

When using auto-generated documentation for Google apps script libraries it's possible to use the Google `prettyprint` class for code samples? I've tried including it in the `pre` tag:
`<pre class="prettyprint">`

but seems to get stripped out during the generation.

Is there also a way to use the @see command to reference functions or external resources inside the code documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous limitations to the gsdoc tags supported by google-apps-script, and you've described just two of them - no support for html element attributes, and limited doc tags. I've described some other issues in [How to preview jsdoc comments in google doc scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461752/how-to-preview-jsdoc-comments-in-google-doc-scripts/12516165#12516165).

There are also open issues:

- [Preview jsDoc documentation from within the script editor](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1731&q=jsdoc&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)
- [Make it easier to show examples by supporting @example in Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1409&q=jsdoc&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)
- [Support Object Oriented Interfaces with documentation for Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1389&q=jsdoc&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

You could add a new issue for your particular concern. The `@see` tag is especially odd, since it appears used in the Base Services documentation, so either the tag works just for Google, or has html substituted for it.

One option is to build and host your documentation on another platform or hosting service. This is what has been done for some of the Notable Libaries, such as the [2D Array Library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/2d-arrays-library#TOC-Reference-documentation). Then, you can generate your docs using jsdoc, and employ the richness of the whole tag set.